# Command pattern for non related recievers in Java with command execute and undo operations

Tags: java, design-patterns

Below is the code I have written to enhance my understanding of Command Pattern in Java. 
As per my study and understanding, when we have some entities [ which we call as receivers ] then Command pattern is useful in encapsulating those unrelated receivers and the operations in command objects. Please provide me feedback on my below implementation of command pattern [more on pattern usage perspective].

**1. AirConditioner.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.recievers;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 *
 */
public class AirConditioner {
    public enum Mode {
            HEAT, COOL
    }

    private Mode acMode;
    private int temperature = 16;

    /**
     * @param newTemp
     * @return
     */
    public boolean setTempreature(int newTemp) {
            boolean isSuccess = false;
            if (newTemp <= 30 && newTemp >= 16) {
                    temperature = newTemp;
                    System.out.println("Temperature has been successfully set as " + temperature);
                    isSuccess = true;
            }
            return isSuccess;
    }

    /**
     * @param newACMode
     */
    public void setACMode(Mode newACMode) {
            this.acMode = newACMode;
            System.out.println("AC mode has been set as " + acMode);
    }

    public void switchOnAC() {
            System.out.println("AC has been switched ON");
    }

    public void switchOffAC() {
            System.out.println("AC has been switched OFF");
    }

    public int getTemp() {
            return temperature;
    }

    public Mode getACMode() {
            return acMode;
    }
}
```

**2. Bulb.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.recievers;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 *
 */
public class Bulb {
    public void setON() {
            System.out.println("Bulb has been switched ON");
    }

    public void setOFF() {
            System.out.println("Bulb has been switched OFF");
    }
}
```

**3. Fan.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.recievers;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 *
 */
public class Fan {
    /**
     * 
     * This enum corresponds to the allowed values for the speed
     *
     */
    public enum Speed {
            ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
    }

    private Speed speed = Speed.ZERO;

    public void switchOn() {
            System.out.println("Fan has been switched on");
    }

    public void switchOff() {
            System.out.println("Fan has been switched off");
    }

    /**
     * @param newSpeed
     */
    public void changeSpeed(Speed newSpeed) {
            speed = newSpeed;
            System.out.println("Speed of the fan has been set as " + speed);
    }

    /**
     * @return Speed of the fan object
     */
    public Speed getSpeed() {
            return speed;
    }
}
```

**4. Microwave.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.recievers;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 *
*/
public class Microwave {
    /**
     * This enum corresponds to the allowed Power for the microwave object
     *
     */
    public enum Power {
            W700, W800, W900, W1000
    }

    private Power power = Power.W700;

    public void switchOnMW() {
            System.out.println("Microwave has been switched ON");
    }

    public void switchOffMW() {
            System.out.println("Microwave has been switched OFF");
    }

    /**
     * @param watt
     */
    public void setPower(Power watt) {
            power = watt;
            System.out.println("Power has been set as " + power);
    }

    /**
     * @return Power for the current Microwave object
     */
    public Power getPower() {
            return power;
    }
}
```

Below are the Command interface and the Concrete Command Classes

**Command Interface**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is the interface which is implemented by the concrete Command
 *         Classes.
 *
 */
public interface Command {
    /**
     * Executed the operation
     */
    public void execute();

    /**
     * reverses the operation performed in the execute method.
     */
    public void undo();
}
```

**1. ACModeCommand.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.AirConditioner;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.AirConditioner.Mode;

/**
 * 
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is Command for handling the AC mode. This encapsulates the
 *         receiver AC object and the operation to perform n it i.e mode setting
 *
 */
public class ACModeCommand implements Command {
    private Mode newACMode;
    private AirConditioner recieverAC;
    private Mode previousModeAC;

    /**
     * This enum is for the clients, in case of some complex code change in the
     * receiver code done later, that can be handled here. This enum shall make
     * the client less dependent on the receiver.
     *
     */
    public enum ACMode {
            HEAT, COOL
    }

    /**
     * @param recieverAC
     * @param modeAC
     */
    public ACModeCommand(AirConditioner recieverAC, ACMode modeAC) {
            this.newACMode = getACMode(modeAC);
            this.recieverAC = recieverAC;
    }

    /**
     * @param acMode
     * @return
     */
    private Mode getACMode(ACMode acMode) {
            return (acMode == ACMode.COOL) ? Mode.COOL : Mode.HEAT;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
            previousModeAC = recieverAC.getACMode();
            recieverAC.setACMode(newACMode);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#undo()
     */
    @Override
    public void undo() {
            recieverAC.setACMode(previousModeAC);
    }

}
```

**2. ACTempreatureCommand.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.AirConditioner;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is the Command class encapsulating the AC object reciever and
 *         the operation on it i.e to set the tempreature
 *
 */
public class ACTempreatureCommand implements Command {
    private AirConditioner recieverAC;
    private int previousTemperature;
    private int newTemperature;
    private boolean isExecuteSucess = false;

    /**
     * @param recieverAC
     * @param newTemperature
     */
    public ACTempreatureCommand(AirConditioner recieverAC, int newTemperature) {
            this.recieverAC = recieverAC;
            this.newTemperature = newTemperature;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
            previousTemperature = recieverAC.getTemp();
            isExecuteSucess = recieverAC.setTempreature(newTemperature);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#undo()
     */
    @Override
    public void undo() {
            // undo only if the execute performed the task i.e. temperature was set
            // as per the client provided temperature.
            if (isExecuteSucess) {
                    recieverAC.setTempreature(previousTemperature);
            }
    }
}
```

**3. FANSpeedCommand.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Fan;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Fan.Speed;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 *
 */
public class FANSpeedCommand implements Command {
    private Fan recieverFan;
    private Speed previousSpeed;
    private Speed newSpeed;

    /**
     * This enum prevents the client from being too much coupled with the
     * receiver code. Client code can control the receivers using Command
     * objects.
     *
     */
    public enum FANSpeed {
            ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
    }

    /**
     * @param recieverFan
     * @param newSpeed
     */
    public FANSpeedCommand(Fan recieverFan, FANSpeed newSpeed) {
            this.recieverFan = recieverFan;
            this.newSpeed = getFanSpeed(newSpeed);
    }

    /**
     * @param speed
     * @return
     */
    private Speed getFanSpeed(FANSpeed speed) {
            Speed fanSpeed = Speed.ZERO;
            switch (speed) {
            case FIVE:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.FIVE;
                    break;
            case FOUR:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.FOUR;
                    break;
            case ONE:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.ONE;
                    break;
            case THREE:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.THREE;
                    break;
            case TWO:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.TWO;
                    break;
            case ZERO:
                    fanSpeed = Speed.ZERO;
                    break;
            }
            return fanSpeed;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
            previousSpeed = recieverFan.getSpeed();
            recieverFan.changeSpeed(newSpeed);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#undo()
     */
    @Override
    public void undo() {
            recieverFan.changeSpeed(previousSpeed);
    }
}
```

**4. MWPowerCommand.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Microwave;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Microwave.Power;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is concrete command object encapsulating the Receiver Microwave
 *         object and the operation to perform on it i.e to set its Power
 *
 */
public class MWPowerCommand implements Command {
    /**
     * This enum prevents the client from being too much coupled with the
     * receiver code. Client code can control the receivers using Command
     * objects.
     *
     */
    public enum MWPower {
            W700, W800, W900, W1000
    }

    private Power previousMWPower;
    private Power newMWPower;
    private Microwave recieverMW;

    /**
     * @param recieverMW
     * @param newPower
     */
    public MWPowerCommand(Microwave recieverMW, MWPower newPower) {
            this.recieverMW = recieverMW;
            this.newMWPower = getMWpower(newPower);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
            previousMWPower = recieverMW.getPower();
            recieverMW.setPower(newMWPower);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#undo()
     */
    @Override
    public void undo() {
            recieverMW.setPower(previousMWPower);
    }

    /**
     * @param power
     * @return
     */
    private Power getMWpower(MWPower power) {
            Power mwPower = Power.W700;
            switch (power) {
            case W1000:
                    mwPower = Power.W1000;
                    break;
            case W700:
                    mwPower = Power.W700;
                    break;
            case W800:
                    mwPower = Power.W800;
                    break;
            case W900:
                    mwPower = Power.W900;
                    break;
            }
            return mwPower;
    }

}
```

**5. OnOffCommand.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands;

import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.AirConditioner;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Bulb;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Fan;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Microwave;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is concrete command object, which enables client code to become
 *         decoupled with the receiver APIs. It provides similar way to switch
 *         on and off an receiver
 *
 */
public class OnOffCommand implements Command {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private Object reciever;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private boolean isToPutOn;

    /**
     * @param reciever
     * @param isToPutOn
     */
    public OnOffCommand(Object reciever, boolean isToPutOn) {
            this.reciever = reciever;
            this.isToPutOn = isToPutOn;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#execute()
     */
    @Override
    public void execute() {
            if (isToPutOn) {
                    executeOn();
            } else {
                    executeOff();
            }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void executeOn() {
            if (reciever instanceof Fan) {
                    ((Fan) reciever).switchOn();
            } else if (reciever instanceof AirConditioner) {
                    ((AirConditioner) reciever).switchOnAC();
            } else if (reciever instanceof Bulb) {
                    ((Bulb) reciever).setON();
            } else if (reciever instanceof Microwave) {
                    ((Microwave) reciever).switchOnMW();
            }

    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void executeOff() {
            if (reciever instanceof Fan) {
                    ((Fan) reciever).switchOff();
            } else if (reciever instanceof AirConditioner) {
                    ((AirConditioner) reciever).switchOffAC();
            } else if (reciever instanceof Bulb) {
                    ((Bulb) reciever).setOFF();
            } else if (reciever instanceof Microwave) {
                    ((Microwave) reciever).switchOffMW();
            }

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command#undo()
     */
    @Override
    public void undo() {
            if (isToPutOn) {
                    executeOff();
            } else {
                    executeOn();
            }
    }

}
```

Below is the **CommandInvoker.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.commands.invoker;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;

import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.Command;

/**
 * @author krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is the invoker class which invokes the execute method on the
 *         command queue.
 *
 */
public class CommandInvoker {
    private Deque<Command> commandQueue;

    public CommandInvoker() {
            commandQueue = new ArrayDeque<Command>();
    }

    public void addCommand(Command newCommand) {
            commandQueue.addFirst(newCommand);
    }

    /**
     * iterates the command queue and performs execution of the commands as set
     * by the client code.
     */
    public void invokeExecute() {
            Iterator<Command> iterator = commandQueue.descendingIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Command cmd = iterator.next();
                    cmd.execute();
            }
    }

    /**
     * Iterates the command queue and performs the undo operation.
     * 
     */
    public void invokeUnDo() {
            Iterator<Command> iterator = commandQueue.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Command cmd = iterator.next();
                    cmd.undo();
            }
    }
}
```

And Finally the **Client.java**

```
package learn.java.commandpattern.client;

import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.ACModeCommand;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.ACTempreatureCommand;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.FANSpeedCommand;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.FANSpeedCommand.FANSpeed;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.MWPowerCommand;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.OnOffCommand;
import learn.java.commandpattern.commands.invoker.CommandInvoker;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.AirConditioner;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Bulb;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Fan;
import learn.java.commandpattern.recievers.Microwave;

/**
 * 
 * @author Krishna.k
 * 
 *         This is the client code. With the use of Command pattern, this code
 *         is very less dependent upon the receiver. By Using Command Pattern it
 *         is also easy to have Undo operations easily.
 */
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Microwave microWave = new Microwave();
            Fan fan = new Fan();
            Bulb bulb = new Bulb();
            AirConditioner ac = new AirConditioner();
            CommandInvoker cmdInvoker = new CommandInvoker();
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new OnOffCommand(microWave, true));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new OnOffCommand(fan, true));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new OnOffCommand(ac, true));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new OnOffCommand(bulb, true));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACModeCommand(ac, ACModeCommand.ACMode.COOL));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 20));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new FANSpeedCommand(fan, FANSpeed.ONE));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new MWPowerCommand(microWave, MWPowerCommand.MWPower.W1000));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new FANSpeedCommand(fan, FANSpeed.TWO));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new FANSpeedCommand(fan, FANSpeed.THREE));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new MWPowerCommand(microWave, MWPowerCommand.MWPower.W700));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new FANSpeedCommand(fan, FANSpeed.FOUR));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 13));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 25));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new MWPowerCommand(microWave, MWPowerCommand.MWPower.W1000));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 17));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 18));
            cmdInvoker.addCommand(new ACTempreatureCommand(ac, 29));
            cmdInvoker.invokeExecute();
            cmdInvoker.invokeUnDo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Code smell using `instanceof`

> ```
>         if (reciever instanceof Fan) {
>                 ((Fan) reciever).switchOn();
>         } else if (reciever instanceof AirConditioner) {
>                 ((AirConditioner) reciever).switchOnAC();
>         } else if (reciever instanceof Bulb) {
>                 ((Bulb) reciever).setON();
>         } else if (reciever instanceof Microwave) {
>                 ((Microwave) reciever).switchOnMW();
>         }
> ```

This usage of instanceof is a code smell, what happens when you buy a new fridge, then this class need to learn how to turn off and on the fridge to.

A better approach to this system would making a `LinePoweredDevice` class/interface, that contains these methods:

```
public interface LinePoweredDevice {
    public void turnOn();

    public void turnOff();
}
```

And then implement it in every class, and adjust your on/off command to this new class.

### Order of cases in a switch should be easy for humans to read

> ```
>         switch (speed) {
>         case FIVE:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.FIVE;
>                 break;
>         case FOUR:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.FOUR;
>                 break;
>         case ONE:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.ONE;
>                 break;
>         case THREE:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.THREE;
>                 break;
>         case TWO:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.TWO;
>                 break;
>         case ZERO:
>                 fanSpeed = Speed.ZERO;
>                 break;
>         }
> ```

You have the options in the following order:

- FIVE
- FOUR
- **ONE**
- THREE
- TWO
- ZERO

When looking at this code, it takes extra long to realize all the constants are there, just because they are in a non-human order.

### Inconsistent naming for name of the temperature variable

> ```
> public boolean setTempreature(int newTemp) {
> public int getTemp() {
> ```

Either have `getTemparature()` and `setTemparature()` or `getTemp()` and `setTemp()`.

### `OnOffCommand` does not respect already on state of a device

This class does not check if a device is already turned on or off, it may happen that this class turns off a light bulb when undoing, even when this bulb was on before the operation even started.

Comment: Thanks for the review... I will correct the enum state order and naming of the setter and getters. For the review comment for the creating a new interface 'LinePoweredDevice'. The receivers are non related. Consider them as code coming from some different libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of instanceOf method.

1. Create Receiver interface (or abstract class)
2. Provide concrete implementation of Receiver.

Command workflow should be like this:

**Client** calls **Invoker** => **Invoker** calls **ConcreteCommand**  => **ConcreteCommand** calls **Receiver** method, which implements abstract **Command** method.

Example:

```
    // On command for TV with same invoker 
    Receiver r = new TV();
    Command onCommand = new OnCommand(r);
    Invoker invoker = new Invoker(onCommand);
    invoker.execute();

    // On command for DVDPlayer with same invoker 
    r = new DVDPlayer();
    onCommand = new OnCommand(r);
    invoker = new Invoker(onCommand);
    invoker.execute();
```

You can find working code at this SE question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276941/how-commnd-pattern-decouples-the-sender-from-reciever/35296198?noredirect=1#comment58524415_35296198

Comment: I understand that instead of instanceof an interface for recievers can be made but as per what I have read and understood, in command pattern receivers are already there may be written by some third parties and may be availabe through some differnent libraries... I mean receivers are not related... as per the UML diagram (generated by staruml for command patrern and also in various places in internet)  does not has a common base interface for receivers... only ICommand is there as base for all concrete commands.

Comment: Like Serializable marker interface, which does not have any relation between implementing classes,  just create IReceiver. It will help to get rid of instanceof call.